Why generative models produce mesh structure at the beginning?
I don't really understand the reason of this. I have listed the outputs of different models below.
Gan (source: self made simple GAN for CIFAR10)

Vq-vae (source: link)

What i mean is illustrated here.
The image that we want to encode then decode (reconstruction)

The input of the model


To provide an answer, it would be helpful to get the sources of your images as well as a bit of elaboration on what i am looking at. Is this the output of the model? Is this somewhere in the middle? What is actually visualized here?

@RobinvanHoorn , edited question
